# How to play video using ypoutube or any other url in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

i want to play video from youtube link or other video url. but video is not play

```
<xct:MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement"Grid.Row="0"   HeightRequest="300"
ShowsPlaybackControls="True" Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPeGkedZykA"/>
```

Comment: That URL doesn't go directly to the _video file_, it goes to an _HTML page_ with its own video player. So you're trying to put a video player inside a video player, which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the youtube url link is a web-based video player, not a direct video link.There are **2** ways that you can play youtube url in Xamarin forms.

****1**.Use [YoutubeExplode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode) plugin.**

```
    <xct:MediaElement x:Name="MyMediaElement" WidthRequest="200" 
     HeightRequest="200"  ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
```

The in your page.cs

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetVideoContent();
    }

    private async void GetVideoContent()
    {
        var youtube = new YoutubeClient();
        // You can specify video ID or URL
        var video = await youtube.Videos.GetAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPeGkedZykA");
        var title = video.Title; // "Downloaded Video Title"
        var author = video.Author; // "Downloaded Video Author"
        var duration = video.Duration; // "Downloaded Video Duration Count"

        //Now it's time to get stream :
        var streamManifest = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPeGkedZykA");

        var streamInfo = streamManifest.GetMuxedStreams().GetWithHighestVideoQuality();

        if (streamInfo != null)
        {
            // Get the actual stream
            var stream = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetAsync(streamInfo);
            MyMediaElement.Source = streamInfo.Url;
        }
    }
```

**2.Use [webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows)**

```
<WebView x:Name="myurl"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="600"></WebView>
```

Then set url in page.cs.

```
 myurl.Source = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPeGkedZykA";
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please help confirm if my answer is helpful to your question?

Comment: but how to get video ended event ?

Comment: this logic is already apply by me but i want to easiest way for get video ended event

Comment: or id any other video url then how can i use media element except youtube? like that https://play.boomstream.com/DLjByq9Z